# How to pass ObservableField inside internal control

Tags: java, android, data-binding, android-databinding

Main view model looks like this:

```
class MainVM{
    public ObservableField<String> title;
    public ObservableField<Boolean> isFlexible;
}
```

main layout looks like:

```
<layout>
  <date><variable name="item" type="MainVM"></data>
  <LinearLayout>
     <TextView text="@{item.title}"/>
     <CustomCtrl1 vm="@{item.isFlexible}">
  </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

and `CustomCtrl`'s layout looks somewhat like

```
   <layout>
      <date><variable name="item" type="boolean"></data>
      <LinearLayout>
          ...
         <Switch checked="@{item}"/>
          ...
      </LinearLayout>
    </layout>
```

The problem is that `ObservableField` from `MainVM` convert's to boolean value when passed to `CustomCtrl` and after that changing boolean value inside `CustomCtrl` don't affect `MainVM`'s. The first idea was change `CustomCtrl's` viewmodel from `Boolean` to `ObservableField<Boolean>` but this not allowed for some reason.

So the question is - what is a proper way to passing down `ObservableField` inside internal controls.

Comment: Are you trying to use an ObservableBoolean as a substitution for 2-way binding?

Comment: yep, looks like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use 2-way binding directly. This requires Android Studio 2.1 and above. Android Studio 2.2 fixes an inflation bug you may hit with custom controls. If you had used an include instead of a custom control, it would be rather trivial:

```
<layout>
  <date><variable name="item" type="MainVM"></data>
  <LinearLayout>
     <TextView android:text="@{item.title}"/>
     <include layout="@layout/other" app:vm="@={item.isFlexible}">
  </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

And other's layout:

```
<layout>
  <date><variable name="item" type="boolean"></data>
  <LinearLayout>
      ...
     <switch android:checked="@={item}"/>
      ...
  </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

With a custom control, you must implement the listener yourself. That means that you must have a listener for the property. I think this should work (I am on a tablet now, so I can't verify):

```
@InverseBindingMethods({
     InverseBindingMethod(type = CustomControl.class, attribute="vm")})
public class CustomCtrl extends View {
    private CustomCtrlBinding binding;
    private InverseBindingAdapter listener;

    public CustomCtrl(...) {
        binding = ...
        binding.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(new OnPropertyChangedCallback() {
            @Overriide
            public void OnPropertyChanged(Observable sender, int propertyId) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onChange();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Bindable
    public boolean getVm() { return binding.getItem(); }

    public void setVm(boolean vm) {
        binding.setItem(vm);
    }

    @BindingAdapter("vmAttrChanged")
    public static void setListener(CustomCtrl view,
            InverseBindingListener listener) {
        view.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

Then you have 2-way binding:

```
<layout>
  <date><variable name="item" type="MainVM"></data>
  <LinearLayout>
     <TextView android:text="@{item.title}"/>
     <CustomCtrl app:vm="@={item.isFlexible}">
  </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

And the custom control layout:

```
<layout>
  <date><variable name="item" type="boolean"></data>
  <LinearLayout>
      ...
     <switch android:checked="@={item}"/>
      ...
  </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

I would normally write a custom control that had its own listener for the attribute, but InverseBindingListener works in a pinch.